# insufficient CUDA runtime version - geforce_gt_220

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, gpu, caffe

I need to run [faster Rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) on GPU, but I have the following error
I have CUDA version <> on UBUNTU 14.04
when I run their demo:

```
common.cpp:104] Cannot create Cublas handle. Cublas won't be available.
E0316 13:17:05.456236 23955 common.cpp:111] Cannot create Curand generator. Curand won't be available.
F0316 13:17:05.462731 23955 common.cpp:142] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (35 vs. 0) CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

driver version

> cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64
>   Kernel Module  340.101  Thu Dec  1 15:52:31 PST 2016 GCC version:  gcc
>   version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)

Our [GPU is this one (geforce_gt_220)](http://www.nvidia.in/object/product_geforce_gt_220_in.html), I have this question as well, can this GPU been manipulated by CUDA runtime API?

Answer (score 2):

Your GPU have a compute capability 1.2, the support for these cards have been removed since CUDA 7.0. If you compile and run with toolkit 6.5 and a driver version > 340 all will be good.

GT 220 is a low end consumer card, don't expect a big speedup it can be slower than some recent core i5 processors.

Comment: may be slower than CPU?

Comment: yes, depending on your CPU  : recent ones for exemple core i5 3770K have 112 GFLOPs, your GPU model 144GFLOPS.

If you add the cost of allocations and memory transfert through PCI-Express it can be slower than a CPU execution.

But you can still reduce the pressure on your host by using your GPU.